# Laplace transform on a finite interval $f(t)= \int_0^1 e^{-xt} f(x) \, dx$

Tags: reference-request, laplace-transform

What is the name of this transform?  It's basically the Laplace transform where we integrate over a finite interval.

$$ F(t)=  \int_0^1 e^{-xt} f(x) \, dx$$

Is it still just the Laplace transform?  Sure we can make the change of variables, $y = \frac{x}{1-x}$ but is there name for the transform when written this way?

Comment: This is just the Laplace transform of the function $$x\mapsto  \begin{cases} f(x)&{\rm if}& 0\leq x\leq 1\cr 0&{\rm if}& 1<x\end{cases} $$

Comment: @OmranKouba OK it is Laplace transform of $f(x)\mathbf{1}(x < 1)$.  Using formulas from [Laplace Transform Table](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/ee102/laplace-table.pdf). I am getting $(1 - e^{-t})\hat{f}(t)$ where $\hat{f}$ is the Laplace transform of $f$.

Comment: Pay attention, wat you get corresponds to 1-periodic functions, but this was not in your assumptions.